# JavaScript get date and day using Date.parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

by using:

```
Date.parse('2015-01-01');
```

it gives output:  Thu Jan 01 2015 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)

but i want just like this:  Thu Jan 01 2015

(moreover i am using it in morris.js chart)

Comment: Isn't parse method of Date returns the number of milliseconds from Jan 1, 1970?

Comment: if possible try to use a date library like http://momentjs.com/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-javascript-date

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lastuser/o6736582/1/

Comment: Seems to me the part you want just happens to be the first 15 characters of the longer date string, so can't you just use a string function like `.substr()` or `.slice()`? (Though it's not clear just how you're getting that longer date string given that `Date.parse()` returns a *number*. **Show your code.**)

Comment: beware that in negative GMT timezones will return the day before

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Conversion_getter

```
new Date('2015-01-01').toDateString();
```

Comment: I want to fix it here but its not working can you please update this js code
    http://jsbin.com/nunusopaca/1/

Comment: I looked at it briefly and i can see the problem occurs not with your code but a leaky abstraction that is you graphing plugin. I'm not gonna spend too much time on that sorry :( I would like to mention that the Date.parse(string) method that you've chosen to use generate a UNIX time which is a NUMBER a very big number counting the amount of milliseconds from 1970. The graphing system you use converts this number into a readable date by it's own conventions. But it's really up to the plugin to decouple that convention. Lastly you should look at FLOT if this is no go. http://www.flotcharts.org/